# Data not rendering while using FlatList in react-native

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I'm trying to render the data entered on the screen using flatlist so that the scroll option works on my app. There's no error displayed but the data is not rendering.

Here's my code:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Button, TextInput, ScrollView, FlatList } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
    const [enteredGoal, setEnteredGoal] = useState('');
    const [courseGoals, setCourseGoals] = useState([]);
    const goalInputHandler = (enteredText) => {
        setEnteredGoal(enteredText);
    };
    const addGoalHandler = () => {
        setCourseGoals(currentGoals => [...courseGoals, { id: Math.random().toString(), value: enteredGoal }]);
    };

    return (
        <View style={styles.screen}>
            <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
                <TextInput placeholder="Course Goal"
                    style={styles.input}
                    onChangeText={goalInputHandler}
                    value={enteredGoal} />
                <Button title="Add" onPress={addGoalHandler} />
            </View>
            <FlatList
                keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.id}
                data={courseGoals} renderItem={itemData => {
                    courseGoals.map((goal) =>
                        <View style={styles.listItem}><Text>{itemData.item.value}</Text></View>)
                }} />

        </View>

    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    screen: {
        padding: 50
    },
    inputContainer: { flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' },
    input: {
        width: '80%', borderColor: 'black', borderWidth: 1, padding: 10
    }
    , listItem: {
        padding: 10,
        margin: 10,
        backgroundColor: '#ccc',
        borderColor: 'black',
        borderWidth: 1
    }
});
```

Could you please help me out?

Answer (score 0):

I think the item is not returned properly in `renderItem` and you don't need to iterate `courseGoals` in it as it is already bind to `data`.

Try update your `renderItem` to this:

```
renderItem={itemData => (
  <View style={styles.listItem}><Text>{itemData.item.value}</Text></View>
)}
```